# Checking multiple table existence in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-cde, pentaho-ctools

I have to check multiple tables available or not. please help me with the [here ETL.PLC_ACCOUNT is a table and I have to check multiple tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gG8ky.jpg) screenshot

Answer (score 0):

According to the screenshot you attached, you're trying to check the table name in a job entry. That only allows for either one static value or variable at the same time.

Instead of that, if you want to validate multiple tables use the transformation step "Table exists". Make sure to have a previous step to set a field containing the list of table names you want to validate.